# NoneType stopping the script with nested functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to achieve the following:

1. Run a script that will upon error call another script.
2. Get the output of that data and insert it into the existing script to update the token value
3. Then display the **"data"**
4. If the value of x is not invalid it will just display the **"data"**

Here is the error I get when the value is not invalid. I do understand why I am getting this error but I'm having an issue handling the script and making it go to the next step

> ```
>     if x not in err_data: TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
> ```

```
url = 'https://somedomain.com/blah/etc'

headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': apikey
}
def check_token():
    x = 'invalid_token'
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    data = response.json()
    err_data = data.get('error')
    #When I get a response "None" I get the above mentioned error and script stops
    if x in err_data:
        refresh_token.ref_token()
        #If that value of x is present run this script that I imported
    else:
        check_data()
        #If the value of x is "None" run this script

def check_data():
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    data = response.json()
    pp(data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    check_token()
    check_data()
    refresh_token.ref_token()
```

Thank you

Comment: What is `err_data` when `data['error']` exists? You should assign an empty value of the same type, e.g., `err_data = data.get('error', [])`.

Comment: The error message refers to `if x not in err_data:`, but that line of code is not in the script you posted.  Please post the real code.

Comment: `err_data = data.get('error')` - the `get` returns `None` if "error" isn't in the dictionary. What do you want to do when there is no "error" key?

Comment: Sorry I was testing different scenarios so I changed it around a bit. Here is the error now:

**if x in err_data:**
**TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable**

Comment: @chepner thank you for the reply. I will try your method but high level I get this:
**{'error': 'invalid_token',....}**

Comment: @tdelaney in case of **None** I am trying to make it run the next fucntion **check_data** or if it can just do a **print(data)** that would work too.

Comment: Ok, then use `data.get('error', '')`. `x in ''` is always `False`(for non-empty `x`). (Though really, it's doesn't matter *what* you assign to `data`, as long as `x in data` is false as desired.)

Comment: @chepner thanks so much, so it looks like your first suggestion. I just added the empty value and that seem to did the trick. I have to do little more testing with it but I think that did the trick. I'm going to save both of your suggestions to see which one works better. Thanks so much again.